# Communicate between two UserControl's

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm working on some application to get more experience with WPF applications.

I manage the application frames with TabItem control of MahApps.Metro library like this:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<TabItem Header="Home">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="2"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Transparent">
            <controlViews:HomeControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Manage">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="2"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <controlViews:ManageControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</TabItem>
```

Each frame have their own class declared like this:

```
public partial class HomeControl : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
    public HomeControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // ....
}
```

HomeControl represent information that could change from "Manage" frame.
I want to create connection between them to update if something were changed
I have the ability to create selectionChange event on MainWindow and detect when user switch to "Home" tab and then update but I manage all his functionality and integration in his own class.

What options I have?

Comment: A WPF application would typically implement the MVVM architectural pattern. The UserControls could then communicate via a shared view model instance, i.e. the DataContext inherited from the MainWindow.

Comment: As a note, `DataContext="{Binding}"` is redundant. It sets the DataContext to the value that it already has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to Bind the Datacontext, since it inherits from it's visual parent (unless you want it otherwise).
DataContext set to MainWindow -> TabControl -> Tabitem -> UserControl

As Clemens commented, you will need a common ViewModel as part of the [MVVM-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), whose Properties are bound to the Visuals inside your UserControl. Updating the values happens in the ViewModel (speaking of a very basic implementation), when Property changes (see: [InotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0))

I made a very basic example for this, see on [GitHub](https://github.com/dbalogh78/WPF_Binding_Basic_example) (It's .net Framework 4.7.2, so the project structure might differ to yours)